# Magento 2 missing body element attributes

Tags: magento2

I updated Magento to 2.4.3 last week, there were a few changes, but the site worked and looked as expected, did the usual deploy and clear cache and it was working great.

Today however, I ran the clear cache command, and all of the body element attributes have gone missing.

Previously I would see

```
<body data-container="body" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope="itemscope" class="page-product-grouped catalog-product-view categorypath-shop category-shop page-layout-1column" aria-busy="false">
```

but now all I have is

```
<body>
```

They body element attributes are missing on every page, catalog/products. At a guess I would assume something is conflicting somewhere, but I've no idea where to start looking. They are missing on the default Luma theme, not just my child theme.

Any ideas where to start looking to debug this?

UPDATE:
I've discovered it was the plugin Mailchimp v103.4.43 by ebizmarts causing the problem. The plugin was installed, but not Enabled. It was after we enabled it and started using it that the issue came about. I've tested the module on a vanilla install and had the same problem. I've raised this with them via email.

Comment: thanks for sharing, MC was the problem

Comment: For me too, MailChimp was causing the issue.